# Perceptron as a Logistic Regression

Tags: perceptron

If by following way single perceptron is made to work like Logistic Regression.
[image]

How much correct is it to say that I made perceptron to work as Logistic Regression.

Question came to mind as activation function of perceptron is a step function and learning is not done by back propagation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron

Also as the activation function is changed and also back propagation is considered to be done then is it still a perceptron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfect to say a logistic regression is a single perceptron. Logistic regression would be a specific case of a perceptron. In fact in Andrew Ng's deep learning specialization, an intuition for perceptron is given by beginning with logistic regression.

Back-propagation helps in scaling up when you add several logistic regressions in series (several hidden layers) and parallel (a single hidden layer). Back propagation for a single perceptron will look like gradient descent for logistic regression.

References

- [DeepLearning Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning?specialization=deep-learning#syllabus)
- [Relevant stackExchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162257/whats-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-perceptron#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20logistic%20regression,classifier%2C%20which%20is%20a%20threshold.)